# Chart.js - creating multiple bar charts on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create 3 bar charts on a single page in such a way that with the change in the select option, each bar graph should appear with different values.
What i have tried so far is

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.c1').show();
  $('.c2').hide();
   $('.c3').hide();
   $('#selectChart').change(function(){
     // $('.Analytic_charts').hide();
    
     var x=$(this).val();
     switch(x){
      case '1':
               $('.c1').show();
               $('.c2').hide();
               $('.c3').hide();
      break;

      case '2':
                $('.c1').hide();
                $('.c2').show();
                $('.c3').hide();
      break;

      case '3':
               $('.c1').hide();
               $('.c2').hide();
               $('.c3').show();
      break;


     }
     
  });
  
  
  var barData1 = {
    labels: ['April 28', 'April 29', 'April 30', 'May 1', 'May 2', 'May 3', 'May 4'],

    datasets: [
        {
            label: '2010 customers #',
            fillColor: '#4A90E2',
            data: [25, 45, 60, 70, 95, 80, 45]
        },
        {
            label: '2014 customers #',
            fillColor: '#50E3C2',
            data: [10, 45, 35, 45, 75, 40, 80]
        }
    ]
};
var barData2 = {
    labels: ['December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],

    datasets: [
        {
            label: '2010 customers #',
            fillColor: '#4A90E2',
            data: [25, 45, 60, 70, 95, 80]
        },
        {
            label: '2014 customers #',
            fillColor: '#50E3C2',
            data: [10, 45, 35, 45, 75, 40]
        }
    ]
};
var barData3 = {
    labels: ['December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'],

    datasets: [
        {
            label: '2010 customers #',
            fillColor: '#4A90E2',
            data: [25, 45, 60, 70, 95, 80]
        },
        {
            label: '2014 customers #',
            fillColor: '#50E3C2',
            data: [10, 45, 35, 45, 75, 40]
        }
    ]
};
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById("Daily").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1).Bar(barData1, {
        responsive : true
    });
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("Weekly").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx2).Bar(barData2, {
        responsive : true
    });
    var ctx3 = document.getElementById("Monthly").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx3).Bar(barData3, {
        responsive : true
    });
}
});
```

```html
 <canvas id="Daily" class="Analytic_charts c1"></canvas>
 <canvas id="Weekly" class="Analytic_charts c2"></canvas>
 <canvas id="Monthly" class="Analytic_charts c3"></canvas>
```

when i change the select option, second and third graphs  are not loading. please anyone help me out with this

Comment: make jsFiddle example

Comment: Check this out -> https://jsfiddle.net/r0qnob1t/

Comment: Great..!! It works like a charm..:)